# Insert and Update Image or File in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I am storing images to the database in the table test (id, name, image), by reading images from a picture box. Please help me.
This is my code:

```
 public byte[] COnvertToBinary(string Path)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(Path);
        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
        data = br.ReadBytes((int) numBytes);
        return data;
    }

    private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog LoadMyFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        LoadMyFile1 .Filter = "REPX Dosyaları(*repx.*) | *.repx*";
        if (LoadMyFile1 .ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = LoadMyFile1 .FileName;
            textBox1.Text = filename;
            db.MyTable.Attach(MyTableBindingSource.Current as MyTable);                                                                  
        }
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DbEntities1 db = new DbEntities1();
        MyTable tbl = new MyTable();
        tbl.MyfileName= textBox1.Text;
        tbl.Myfile= COnvertToBinary(textBox1.Text);
        db.MyTable.Add(tbl);
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved.");
    }
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? I see no SQL there. Perhaps you should have the <sql-server> tag instead.

Comment: i connect to db with ADO.Net Entity Data Model @jarlh

Comment: You are sure to add a "Table" and not a "Row" ? Normaly, you do not use Table but directly the name of the Table (ex: MyTableOfImage.File = Convert(textbox1.Text))

Comment: @Digital3D  tbl.file= COnvert(textBox1.Text);  file it is row name in my table. I corrected(edit) the names to be understood

Comment: Your question is lacking vital information. What happens when the code is run? Error message? Unhandled exception? Nothing?